# Loading 12-Bit Raw GreyScale Image using Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working with opencv 2.4.9. I would like to load a 12-Bit grey scale raw(.raw) image stored as Y16(16-Bit) format.This format contains only a single, 16 bit Y plane for monochrome images. Each pixel is represented by a 16 bit, little endian format.

I used the following code for loading the image.

```
Mat Img_Source16Bit_Gray(m_ImgWidth,m_ImgHeight,CV_16UC1);
Mat Img_Destination8Bit_Gray;

FILE * f; 
f=fopen(FileName_S.c_str(),"rb");
if ( !f )
{
    MessageBox(L"File Not Found");
    return;
}
uchar* Pixels_Char_16Bit;
Pixels_Char_16Bit = new uchar[m_ImgWidth * m_ImgHeight *2];

fread(Pixels_Char_16Bit,m_ImgWidth * m_ImgHeight*2,1,f);
fclose(f);

Img_Source16Bit_Gray.data= Pixels_Char_16Bit;

Img_Source16Bit_Gray.convertTo(Img_Destination8Bit_Gray,CV_8UC1,1);

imshow("Img_Source16Bit_Gray",Img_Source16Bit_Gray);
imshow("Img_Destination8Bit_Gray",Img_Destination8Bit_Gray);
```

Actual image is shown in the right side & the output left hand side I'm getting is not correct & the Result8 bit image is full of white pixels. Can anyone please provide me the steps to load a 16 Bit grey scale image?

[image]

Comment: The "12" in the title is a typo? Did you try cv::imread with anydepth parameter?

Comment: No 12-Bit is not a typo.As you know that 12-Bit data is stored as 16-Bit format. Yes i tried imread with IMREAD_ANYDEPTH param & it throws exception.

Comment: btw, (should not be the problem but will give you problems later on access): in your Mat creation you have width and height swapped. it should be `Mat Img_Source16Bit_Gray(m_ImgHeight,m_ImgWidth,CV_16UC1)`

Comment: could you verify that `Pixels_Char_16Bit` has the right values after fread?

Comment: Hmm, is `Img_Source16Bit_Gray.convertTo(Img_Destination8Bit_Gray,CV_8UC1,1);` just throwing away the 8 least significant bits converting your 12 bpp image to a 4bpp image?

Comment: Perhaps you need to use the technique in the last example here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html Start reading from `double minVal, maxVal;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for helping me to find the answer! Here is my updated code.

```
Mat Img_Source16Bit_Gray(m_ImgHeight,m_ImgWidth,CV_16UC1);
Mat Img_Destination8Bit_Gray(m_ImgHeight,m_ImgWidth,CV_8UC1);

FILE * f; 
f=fopen(FileName_S.c_str(),"rb");
if ( !f )
{
    MessageBox(L"File Not Found");
    return;
}

char16_t* pY16Pixels;//w-2592 h- 1944
pY16Pixels = new char16_t[m_ImgWidth * m_ImgHeight];

fread(pY16Pixels,m_ImgWidth*m_ImgHeight*2,1,f);
Img_Source16Bit_Gray.data= reinterpret_cast<uchar*>(pY16Pixels);

double minVal, maxVal;
minMaxLoc(Img_Source16Bit_Gray, &minVal, &maxVal); //find minimum and maximum intensities
Img_Source16Bit_Gray.convertTo(Img_Destination8Bit_Gray, CV_8U, 255.0/(maxVal - minVal), -minVal * 255.0/(maxVal - minVal));

namedWindow("Img_Source16Bit_Gray",WINDOW_NORMAL);
namedWindow("Img_Destination8Bit_Gray",WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("Img_Source16Bit_Gray",Img_Source16Bit_Gray);
imshow("Img_Destination8Bit_Gray",Img_Destination8Bit_Gray);
```